# How to select a proper transistor?

Tags: transistors, component-selection

I've got a schematic that calls for an unspecified "NPN Negistor". From my understanding of the circuit, the NPN is an oscillator that generates two audio tones for testing. Here's the schematic:
[image]

I've got a drawer full of about a dozen flavors of NPNs, how on earth do I choose which one to use with such sketchy information?

Comment: post the schematic, or provide a link and one of use here will post it for you.

Comment: @rawbrawb - posted....

Comment: From what I can work out of the switch arrangement it's off plus two frequencies from switching the cap but otherwise a simple oscillator. Just pointing that out because as Phil said you might as well just try it, if you already have a 12 odd DC supply you should only need say Q1, C4, C5 and the 1K resistor to try it out.

Comment: Polarity of D1 and D2 is wrong!

Comment: This circuit is junk.  Forget about it and walk away.

Comment: @Curd - yeah I noticed the diode polarity and already made the adjustment when designing the PCB. Thanks!

Comment: @Olin - Can you please elaborate? What's wrong with it (apart from the diode bridge polarity, which I've already noted and corrected for on my breadboard) that causes it to be junk?

Comment: @dwwi: Seriously?  You don't think a major stupidity like getting a simple full wave bridge wrong is clear evidence whoever did this doesn't know what they are doing?  Then there is "schematic of the circuit *designer*".  Huh?  He was a robot?  "5 uF" caps?  Obviously never even tried to put a kit together.  We can't tell how S2 is supposed to function.  In general, it's a mess and the author clearly doesn't know what he's doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an interesting circuit...

I can find references of [BC547](http://www.vk2zay.net/article/157) and [2N2222](http://www.keelynet.com/zpe/negistor.htm) being used as negistors. This might be a "try it and see if it works" sort of situation.

Comment: both of which I have on the workbench. I'll see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Reversed diodes and negistor selection aren't really a problem, given a few simplifications:

[image: simplified schematic]

Comment: brilliant indeed.